# vscode: goto implementations peeks definitions (golang)

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

I have an issue when navigating my code.

The goto implementations command (and also Find All Implementations) returns methods definitions along implementations.

Consider the following external module:

```golang
type API interface {
    SendMessage(context.Context, string) error  // <- definition
}

type myApiImpl struct {}

func (a myApiImpl) SendMessage(ctx context.Context, msg string) error { // <- implementation
     return nil
}
```

And the following code:

```golang
func sendMsg(msg string) error {
    var api API
    api = myApiImpl{}
    return apiImpl.SendMessage(context.TODO(), msg) // <- reference
}
```

When using the goto implementation on 'reference' (from my example) vscode prompt me with a choice between the definition and the implementation of the external module.

I expect the goto implementation to only peek at the implementation and not the definition.

This behaviour only occurs when the interface and implementation are located in an external module. When applying the same code but inside a single module (with two packages or not) the goto implementations work as expected.

Comment: Don't `Ctrl+F12` for mac (`Cmd+F12`) work for this?

Comment: Shortcut depends on local configuration. I'm talking about specific commands which you can see by right-clicking the function directly.
"Go to Definitions" "Go to Implementations" "Go to References"